# Vídeo como fondo en Un DIV

Tags: html, html5, css, css3

Tengo un problema con mi sitio (http://osaka.incloudmarketing.com/) y es el siguiente, quiero poner un vídeo en el slider de mi sitio, ya logre avanzar, el punto es que en google chrome el vídeo se ve solo en el contenedor del slider, mientras que en en mozilla se expande a todo el alto del sitio tapando el contenido.

**Codigo HTML:**

```
<div class="video-container">
<video autoplay class="fillWidth visible-lg" poster="http://sandbox.thewikies.com/vfe-generator/images/big-buck-bunny_poster.jpg">
<source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
<source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.webm" type="video/webm" />
<source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
Tu navegador no soporta HTML5 Video
```

**Codigo CSS**

```
.video-container{
top: 0%;
left: 0%;
height: 650px;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;}

video.fillWidth {
background-size: cover;
bottom: 0;
height: auto;
min-height: 100%;
min-width: 100%;
position: fixed;
right: 0;
width: auto;
z-index: -100;
visibility: visible;}
```

Pregunto como lograr que se vea en mozilla como si el video estuviese dentro del DIV? tal y como se ve en google chrome

Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema tiene que ver con el contexto de apilamiento ([*stacking context*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) en inglés). Los elementos de una página HTML se ordenan a lo largo de un eje imaginario Z (X e Y serían su posición horizontal y vertical) que indica la profundidad de cada elemento dentro del documento.

Esa posición/profundidad variará dependiendo del orden de aparación dentro del documento y del valor de diferentes atributos como `position`, `z-index`, `display`, `filter`, `perspective`, `transform`, etc.

El orden de apilamiento sería el siguiente de menor a mayor (mientras más alto, más arriba aparecerá en la visualización):

- Elemento raíz
- Elementos posicionados con un `z-index` negativo (según su valor)
- Elementos no posicionados
- Elementos posicionados sin `z-index` o con `z-index:auto` (según su orden de aparición)
- Elementos posicionados con `z-index` positivo (según su valor)

Parece que Chrome está interpretando el orden de apilamiento de una manera (que es la que quieres), mientras que Firefox e Internet Explorer lo hacen de otra (que no te gusta). No estoy diciendo que un navegador lo esté haciendo mejor o peor que otro, pero diría que por ahí va el problema en general.

Y más concretamente en que aunque el vídeo tiene un `z-index` de -100, uno de sus contenedores tiene un `z-index` de 6 (`#rev_slider_menu-top_wrapper`), y el resto de elementos en la página que quieres que estén por encima del vídeo no tienen `z-index` o `position` definidos. Lo que hace parece estar volviendo un poco locos a los navegadores.

**Solución**

Una solución al problema sería añadir `position:relative` con un `z-index` mayor que 6 a todos los elementos que quieres que estén por encima del vídeo... o para simplificar el asunto: envuelve todos esos elementos dentro de un `div` y asígnale (sólo a ese `div`) una posición relativa con `z-index` de 7 (y ya de paso un `background-black` para que se vea bien).

Algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Perfecto, esta es la respuesta, mi problema quedo solucionado! Gracias